# Core Data double-inserting child records in one-to-many association

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, objectmapper

We have an iOS application that uses Core Data to persist records fetched from a private web API. One of our API requests fetches a list of `Project` records, each of which has multiple associated `Location` records. ObjectMapper is used to deserialize the JSON response, and we have a custom transformer that assigns the nested `Location` attributes to a Core Data association on the `Project` entity.

The relevant part of the code looks like this. It's executed within a PromiseKit promise (hence the `seal`), and we save first to a background context and then propagate to the main context that gets used on the UI thread.

```
WNManagedObjectController.backgroundContext.perform {
    let project = Mapper<Project>().map(JSONObject: JSON(json).object)!

    try! WNManagedObjectController.backgroundContext.save()

    WNManagedObjectController.managedContext.performAndWait {
        do {
            try WNManagedObjectController.managedContext.save()
            seal.fulfill(project.objectID)
        } catch {
            seal.reject(error)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem we're having is that this insert process is saving each `Location` record to the database *twice*. Strangely, the duplicated `Location` records don't have any association with  their parent `Project` record. That is to say, if `Location` records are looked up with an `NSFetchRequest`, or if I run a query on the underlying SQLite database, I can see that there are two entries for each `Location`, but `project.locations` only returns one copy of each  `Location`. The same (or very similar) process applied to other record types with the same structure also results in duplicates.

I've tried several things so far to narrow down the problem:

- Inspected the API JSON - no duplicates.
- Inspected the state of the `project.locations` property immediately before the Core Data write. No duplicate records are present prior to the objects being persisted, indicating that the deserializer and custom nested attributes transformer are working correctly.
- Removed the block that propagates the changes to the main thread managed object context, in case this was causing the insert to occur twice. Still get duplicates with solely the write to the background context.
- Run the app with `com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` set. No exception is thrown in this process, confirming that it's not a thread safety issue of some kind.
- Run the app with `com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` set. I can see in the logs that Core Data is inserting exactly twice as many `Location` rows as expected into the underlying SQLite database.
- Implemented a uniqueness constraint on the entity. This fixes the problem in terms of what data gets persisted, but will still throw an error unless an `NSMergePolicy` is set.

The last item in that list effectively solves the problem, but it's treating the symptom, not the cause. Data integrity is important for our application, and I'm looking to understand what the underlying problem might be, or other options I might pursue for investigating it further.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the relationship have an inverse?

Comment: @pbasdf yes, the relationship does have an inverse.

Comment: I would try overriding awakeFromInsert for the Location class, put in a breakpoint, and see if the backtrace gives you any clues as to what code is calling the insert.

Comment: @pbasdf Thanks for the suggestion! I tried this, and `awakeFromInsert` is indeed being called twice for each `Location` - once for the background context, from within the `Location` constructor, and then again when the changes are propagated to the parent context. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856122/why-is-awakefrominsert-called-twice) suggests that's normal though, so I'm not sure if there's anything to be made of the repeated call.

Comment: So, two calls to awakefrominsert for each Location - but still two Location objects (so 4 awakefrominsert calls) for each location in the JSON.  Does the backtrace give any information as to the code that led to the inserts?

Comment: @pbasdf  Actually only two `awakeFromInsert` calls for each location in the JSON, sorry if I was unclear. The duplicate `Location` objects don't manifest themselves right away - I can see them in the underlying SQLite database after the context gets persisted, and then subsequent `NSFetchRequest`s return duplicate location objects. But immediately after the initial insert into the context, before persistence, there doesn't appear to be any duplication.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser... so in your code above the duplication happens not in the Mapper.map call, but after the context save?

Comment: @pbasdf that seems to be the case. Neither `awakeFromInsert` nor the contents of `project.locations` indicate any duplication from ObjectMapper.

Comment: Clutching at straws: anything in `willSave` for Project or Location that might generate the extra objects when the save is triggered?

Comment: @pbasdf I'm afraid not, I'm not making use of `willSave` at all. Thank you for your efforts on this, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A year and eight months later, I finally got to the bottom of this bug when a similar issue occurred with a different set of records. The problem was that I was calling ObjectMapper on each `Location` object twice. I was using ObjectMapper's `mapArray` method within a custom ObjectMapper `TransformType` to deserialize and persist the `Location` records associated with each `Project`, which worked as follows:

```
let locations = Mapper<Location>().mapArray(JSONObject: value as AnyObject)
```

However, what I had overlooked is that I was also overriding the constructor for `Location` and calling ObjectMapper *again* there:

```
required public init?(map: Map) {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Location", in: WNManagedObjectController.backgroundContext)
    super.init(entity: entity!, insertInto: WNManagedObjectController.backgroundContext)
    mapping(map: map)
}
```

The line `mapping(map: map)` was unnecessary, and proved to be the culprit. In a similar scenario with two levels of one-to-many associations, this had the somewhat amusing consequence of quadrupling (!) the records at the second level - their parents had been duplicated, each copy of which subsequently duplicated its children. This was what ultimately led me to the cause of the bug.